# Its possible to connect remote appium server?

Tags: appium

I'm trying to run appium in remote server and running test cases connecting android device in local system and i'm getting error could not find a connected android device..

Answer (score 3):

If you initialize your driver with remote address you should not have any problem:

**Python code**

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

**Java code**

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

**C# code**

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri(""http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub""), capabilities);
```

The only thing is... ***Your device must be connected directly to 192.168.1.50 machine where Appium is running***

Comment: I have never tied but you can use Appium grid concept. Run node where your device is connected and registered with appium server. In this way you can achieve this

Comment: Thanks for the replay.How to configure appium grid.Is there any documentation or any link to achieve this..

Comment: @chandru Look this: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/grid.md

Comment: But in this process also we need to run appium server in local system not in remote system right.

Comment: You have to read... You can use grid replacing 'host_name_appium_server_or_ip-address_appium_server' for your IP. And your devices must be connected to your remote server

Comment: what i tried test cases in local system and appium and device or emulator in remote server in this scenario its working.But i need to run appium in remote and test cases and device or emulator in local system this scenario its not working.Server is started in remotoly its returning error device not connected.

Comment: Because device **MUST** be connected to the same server where Appium is running

Comment: Maybe you can try connecting your local device to remote server with adb over TCP

Comment: I have tried to connect using adb connect command in remote server with local system ip.its not connecting.

Comment: Can I run appium on server and connect my real own mobile phone to the apium server ?