# How to get remotely connected devices in remote appium server?

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, appium

I'm using a appium server to run test remotely with java, But I don't know how to get the devices connected to that machine remotely.
Anyone know how to get (remotely) the devices connected in machine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868076/its-possible-to-connect-remote-appium-server/47869577#47869577

Comment: I want the devices connected to the remote machine...

Comment: At the same machine where Appium is executing?

Comment: yes. The remote machine has the appium and the devices.

Comment: Ok then where is the problem? Look my answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869577/3685973

Comment: driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities); where 192.168.1.50 is your remote machine address

Comment: I get it... but the capabilities don't already have the device? like this: cap.setCapability("deviceName", "xxxxxxxx");
And I want all devices connected before starting the driver...

Comment: What do you mean by "I want all devices connected before starting the driver..."?

Comment: something like "adb devices"

Comment: You will have to use Appium Grid or create X appium servers (with different ports) for X number of devices...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute just a test but have multiple devices... You have to use an identifier:

**Example**:

```
node appium -U "Device_identifier"
```

Because you have to tell Appium with which device has to work with...
*You can get* Device_identifier *with "adb devices"*.

If you want them to run at the same time you will need to create X "node appium" executions with different ports...

**Example**:

```
node appium -p 4723 -bp 4724 -U "Device1_identifier"
node appium -p 4725 -bp 4726 -U "Device2_identifier"
```

And after that you will have to create two drivers

**Java code**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities1.setCapability(...);
driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities1);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities2 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities2.setCapability(...);
driver2= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://192.168.1.50:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel appium should provide an end point by which we get the list of all connected devices.

**Work around**
Execute [this jar](https://github.com/navneet-kumar/basic-appium-capabilities/tree/master/output) file on the remote server which has the connected devices.

After that you can just get the list of connected devices using this end point 
`http://<Ip of machine>:4567/devices`